# Can I use spark3.3.1 and hive3 together?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm new to spark. Now I want to use spark to read some data and write it to the tables defined by hive. I'm using spark3.3.1 and hadoop 3.3.2, and now, can I download hive3 and config spark3 work together? Because some materials I found from internet told me spark can't work with all versions of hive

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Spark 3.2.1 documentation it is compatible with Hive 3.1.0 if the versions of spark and hive can be modified I would suggest you to use the above mentioned combination to start with.

Comment: hi，would you like tell me the section in spark3.2.1 document about the compatible

Answer (score 0):

I try to integrate hive 3.1.2 with spark 3.2.1. There is a hive fork for spark 3:
https://github.com/forsre/hive3.1.2

You can use it to recompile hive with spark 3 and hive on spark can work.

But spark thrift server is incompatible with hive 3. Apache kyuubi is suggested to replace spark thrift server and hiveserver2.

https://kyuubi.apache.org/

You can just use standard hive 3.1.2 and spart 3.2.1 package with kyuubi 1.6.0 to make them work.